# How can I use a reentrancy attack to permanently freeze funds?

Tags: solidity, ethereumj, reentrant-attacks, hack

If possible, can you please send me the code with as much details as possible? I would like to understand more about it but didn't find useful content on the internet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What funds are you talking about? We would need to look at the code of the target smart contract to tell. Maybe the target smart contract is not even exploitable with reentrancy.

I literally can’t help you without some code